# Facebook ShareDialog with Robovm bindings Robopods

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I have a libgGDX game compiled to iOS by RoboVM where I want to share a link in Facebook.

I'm using the new Robovm bindings Robopods, please see this link: https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods

I'm trying to open a facebook Share Dialog to share a link but it doesn't work.

I initiate like this:

```
@Override
public boolean didFinishLaunching(UIApplication application, UIApplicationLaunchOptions launchOptions) {
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.getSharedInstance().didFinishLaunching(application, launchOptions);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean openURL(UIApplication application, NSURL url, String sourceApplication, NSPropertyList annotation) {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.getSharedInstance().openURL(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
}

@Override
public void didBecomeActive(UIApplication application) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp();
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool();
UIApplication.main(argv, null, IOSLauncher.class);
pool.close();
```

}

and I'm trying to open the Share Dialog as:

```
NSURL urlShare = new NSURL("http://web.page.com");
FBSDKShareLinkContent content = new FBSDKShareLinkContent();
content.setContentURL(urlShare);

dialog = new FBSDKShareDialog();
dialog.setFromViewController(getWindow().getRootViewController());
dialog.setShareContent(content);
dialog.show();
```

But it doesn't work as I think I'm making something wrong. Could someone help on this?

Thanks a lot!

(by the way thanks for the robopods authors for the good job)

Comment: How does the user login to facebook ? I can't see it in the part of the code you provided.

Comment: there is a sample on how you should do it. Please check the facebook sample here https://github.com/robovm/robovm-samples/tree/master/robopods/facebook